# What are the wysiwyg editors that have proven to be reliable at large scale?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg, jwysiwyg

I recently heard that jWYSIWYG editor isn't a reliable editor for a large scale website.  Are there other WYSIWYG editors that have proven to be reliable on a large scale?

Thanks,
Walker

Comment: I'm not sure whether "large scale" really is a criterion here: All the WYSIWYG editors operate solely on the client side, with the small exception of file uploads and such. What exactly is your focus?

Comment: http://www.queness.com/post/212/10-jquery-and-non-jquery-javascript-rich-text-editors

Comment: I guess I mean something that's solid and doesn't have bugs that begin to appear when you have a larger userbase.

I heard there were problems with jWYSIWYG?  I customized it and added it and it seems to work great (only 25kb), but I've heard fairly bad things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Ckeditor:

http://ckeditor.com/who-is-using-ckeditor

### MCE:

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/using.php

These have a pretty solid and respectable large-scale userbase.

Answer (score 1):

Since JS-based WYSIWYG editors works on the client side I believe they have not much to do with web applications scalability. The only important thing is maybe code size...